# Selecting Datalabels from Series Data

Tags: highcharts

I have series data set as

```
series0 = [[x0,y0,name0],[x1,y1,name1],[x2,y2,name2]...]
```

and can easily pick `x` or `y` values to use in the dataLabel with format: `{point.y}` for example, but can't work out how to access the name value.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you made your series like so:

`series0 = [ {x:x0,y:y0,name:name0},{x:x1,y:y1,name:name1},{x:x2,y:y2,name:name2}...]`

then you could use `{point.name}` in your labels

http://jsfiddle.net/TuVZQ/

Comment: It is an array of data, not series.

Comment: If the array of arrays can be transformed into an array of objects, then point naming will work just fine.

Comment: Works a treat and thanks for responding so quickly(and correcting my terminology Sebastian). Happy weekend all.